# Manipulate plot

Tags: plotting, manipulate

How can one do this:

```
Manipulate[ 
 Plot[  -Log[
    1 - s x + (s^2 x^2)/2 - ((4 c - 4 s^2 + s^4) x^3)/(
     4 (-3 + 2 s)) + (s (8 c - 8 s^2 + 3 s^3) x^4)/(8 (-3 + 2 s)) - (
     s (8 c - 8 s^2 + 3 s^3) x^5)/(20 (-3 + 2 s))    ], {x, -2, 
   2} ], {c, 0.01, 0.2}, {s, 0.1, 1.5}]
```

(which works fine) without explicitly having the expression in the manipulate statement. It is not obvious from the link so I fail to see how this is a duplicate.

For example, why doesn't this work?

```
rule = { z -> -Log[
      1 - s x + (s^2 x^2)/2 - ((4 c - 4 s^2 + s^4) x^3)/(
       4 (-3 + 2 s)) + (s (8 c - 8 s^2 + 3 s^3) x^4)/(
       8 (-3 + 2 s)) - (s (8 c - 8 s^2 + 3 s^3) x^5)/(
       20 (-3 + 2 s))] };
Manipulate[
  Plot[z /. rule, {x, 0, 10}],
             {c, 0.1, 0.5},
             {s, 0.1, 0.4}
 ]
```

I'd like to know what to do if

i) I have a function f[x,c,s] . This is what I've tried:

```
f[x_, s_, 
  c_ ] = -Log[ 
   1 - s x + (s^2 x^2)/2 - ((4 c - 4 s^2 + s^4) x^3)/(
    4 (-3 + 2 s)) + (s (8 c - 8 s^2 + 3 s^3) x^4)/(8 (-3 + 2 s)) - (
    s (8 c - 8 s^2 + 3 s^3) x^5)/(20 (-3 + 2 s))]
Manipulate[ Plot[ f[x, c, s], {x, -2, 2} ],
      {c, 0.1, 0.3},
      {s, 0.1, 0.5} 
 ]
```

ii) I have an expression  in x, c,s

Comment: I may be missing something here, but if you have a well defined function f[x,c,s] all you have to do is put `f[x,c,s]` as `Plot`s first argument. All the necessary variables are visible to `Manipulate` then and it it should just work as explained in Karsetn's link.

Comment: In your latest update you haven't put any **visible** references to x, c, and s in the expression, which is necessary. Again, this is explained in the link.

Comment: What's your problem with case i)? It works as expected. For your second case, you have to make the variables visible. Just define `g[x_, s_, c_] = z /. rule` outsize of the manipulate or with its `Initialization` option and use `g[x, c, s]` in the plot.

Comment: Your block of code in the middle works, if you use `With[{rule = rule},
 Manipulate[Plot[z /. rule, {x, 0, 10}], {c, 0.1, 0.5}, {s, 0.1, 0.4}]
 ]`, as shown in the possible duplicate.